# prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ can not be $G_{\delta}$ set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ can not be $G_{\delta}$ set in $\mathbb{R}$.

let $\mathbb{Q}$ is $G_{\delta}$ set. then $\mathbb{Q}=\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}\  O_i$.

for open sets $O_i$. now each open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is countable union of disjoints  open intervels .
then each open set $O_i$ containg $\mathbb{Q}$ must be of the form $\mathbb{R}/P_i,$ where $P_i$  contain countable many irrationals points.

i am not getting this last line that $O_i =\mathbb{R}/P_i,$ with $P_i$  contain countable many irrationals points.

any hint.thanks in advanced.

Comment: The standard proof of this uses the Baire category theorem, and shows that $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is $G_\delta$ also.

Comment: In the ever-reliable Wikipedia, the article on $G_\delta$ sets proves this statement by appealing to the Baire CategoryTheorem. So this outsider to the area would guess that any proof of your fact would involve fairly deep mathematics.